# Fetch distinct column values in Druid

Tags: druid

I am having a data source with multiple dimensions. name and jobFamily are two of the dimensions. Now I want to fetch distinct names along with jobFamily from DRUID.

sql query :

```
select DISTINCT name, jobfamily from datasource
```

Can someone help me to write a JSON query?

Answer (score 2):

Below query solved my problem

```
{
  "queryType": "groupBy",
  "dataSource": "junk5",
  "granularity": "hour",
  "dimensions": [
    "name", "jobfamily"
  ],
  "intervals": ["2010-01-01T00:00/2020-01-01T00"]
}
```